# foreign_key: belongs_to & has_one difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, models

I don't understand difference of those 2 association types.

For example, we have 2 tables:

**boxers**

```
[ id, name, title ]
```

**titles**

```
[ id, name ]
```

So, we can specify our associations this way:

**boxer.rb**

```
belongs_to :title, forign_key: "title"
```

And then use it like Boxer.find(1).title.name

Logically, each boxer always has one record in titles and each title has many boxers.

So why wouldn't we specify `has_one` and `has_many` relations? And when i specify `belongs_to :title, forign_key: "title"`, it means that FK point on table boxers in my case (**boxer.rb**). But when I try to write `has_one :title, forign_key: "title"`, it search column `title` in `titles` table. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You put the `belongs_to` on the model with the foreign key index into the other model.  On the other model, you put the `has_one`.  Both allow you to override the name of the fk column, but it's always in the table with the`belongs_to`.

I use this trick to remember:

A dog `belongs_to` his owner (not the other way around), and the owner `has_one`  dog.  The dog wears the **id** tag with his owner's number, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Generically, if you do not mention any thing, and just write the following:

```
class Boxer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :title
end
```

And then you do:

```
boxer = Boxer.find_by_id(1)
puts boxer.title
```

`boxer.title`; it goes into `titles` table, and searchs there for a row where the `id` is same as the `boxer_id` stored in the object on which you are calling the method `boxer.title`.

That goes when you do not specify a `foreign_key` in the model.

But if you do specify a `foreign_key` like following:

```
class Boxer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :title, foreign_key: 'title'
end
```

Now, in `boxers` table, there must be a column `title` that will store the `id` of of title it belongs to.

The difference is just: If you do not specify a `foreign_key`, it will go and look for `title_id`, but when you specify a `foreign_key`, it will search for that one instead.

Comment: Yes, i understand all that, but the question is about has_one. FK acts different when specify it in has_one association. It search for column you specified with FK in other table. so `has_one :title, foreign_key: 'title' ` will search not for `title` in **boxers**, but in **titles** table. And i can't understand why?

Comment: Foreign Key always exists in the table who belongs to the other table. For example, a computer `belongs_to` a user, foreign key will exist in computer.  In your case, `title` belongs_to `boxer`, so obviously foreign key should exists in `titles` table, and that's where it exists.

Comment: Ok, got it. But what about `has_one`, where it expects FK?

Comment: Like in your case, `boxer` has_one `title`, so by default `boxer` will look for a key named `boxer_id` in `titles` table, NOT IN `boxers` table. And when you say, boxer `has_one :title, foreign_key: title`, that key named `boxer_id` will now by simply replaced with `title` key, because that's what you have mentioned in your code. Always remember, the FK exists in the table who `belongs_to` the other table.

Comment: And most important of all, if you have specified `foreign_key` in title model, you also have to specify the same foreign_key in other model: Boxer, otherwise it won't work for the current scenario.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And what do you mean I have to specify the foreign key in both models?

Comment: If you specify `foreign_key` in one, you must specify in other table too. So that both table know how to to find each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion may stem from the association between your models being somewhat counterintuitive. You're saying each `boxer` has one `title`, but each `title` may have multiple `boxers`, correct? In that case, while intuitively we'd talk about titles belonging to boxers, your association should actually be the other way around: each title has many boxers, and each boxer belongs to one title. So:

```
# title
has_many :boxers

# boxer
belongs_to :title
```

Where you have a `has_one` or `has_many` association in Rails, the other side must always have `belongs_to`, and this should be on the model that has the foreign_key to the other table. From the above, Rails would normally assume that the `boxers` table has a column called `title_id`, which would correspond to the values in the `id` column of `titles`. Given you've not done that, you'll need to provide the additional information so Rails can properly handle the association.

Specifically, you'll need to tell Rails that the Boxer model is using `title` as it's foreign key, and that this corresponds to the Title's `name`:

```
# title
has_many :boxers, primary_key: :name, foreign_key: :title

# boxer
belongs_to :title, foreign_key: :title
```

I'd recommend instead moving to a more standard setup, and dropping the `title` field on boxer in favour of a `title_id`. It's probably also worth having a look through the [RailsGuide on Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), as that has quite a bit of detail on exactly how all this works.